# Retrieving Lat Log data from Firebase and put on Map as marker

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, latitude-longitude

I am stuck with this issue related to retrieving data from my firebase database. I have pushed the following details on my database using the following android code.

```
                scanString = intent.getStringArrayListExtra( "beaconList" );
            nameList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra( "nameList" );
            addressList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra( "addressList" );
            RssiList = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra( "RssiList" );

            for ( int i=0; i < scanString.size(); i++) {
                addBeacon.name = nameList.get( i );
                addBeacon.address = addressList.get( i );
                addBeacon.Rssi = RssiList.get( i );
                addBeacon.latitude = mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                addBeacon.longitude = mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
                databaseReference.child( "foo" ).push().setValue( addBeacon);
```

and i get following databse structure.

Now i want to get this lat & long value from the database and put marker on the map with these coordinates.

I am using following code for that.

```
   scanString.add("11");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "foo" ).child( "-KltK9gp7g5h1YpqaCmW" );

        //databaseReference.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        //databaseReference.addChildEventListener( new ChildEventListener() {

        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Log.d("Child Event,longitude", dataSnapshot.getKey());
                addBeacon = dataSnapshot.getValue( beacon.class );
                scanString.add("add beacon retrieved");
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Log.d("Child Event,longitude","onChildChanged:"+ dataSnapshot.getKey());
                addBeacon = dataSnapshot.getValue( beacon.class );
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
       databaseReference.push().setValue( scanString);
    }
```

It will be really great if someone can help. Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: The main problem is synchronization between the Firebase database and application. We want to retrieve value in real time  as child is added but that's not happening. The value gets updated with lot of delay so it is not possible to put marker on the map in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a marker on a map, you will first need a map and its reference (such as `GoogleMap mMap`)

If you have such a reference, all you need to do is convert your coordinates into a LatLng instance and add a marker:

```
LatLng coord = new LatLng(addBeacon.latitude, addBeacon.longitude);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(coord)
    .title("Hello world"));
```

You can obtain more information about markers [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#add_a_marker):

As a side note, if you have problems retrieving your data from Firebase and you want to retrieve your data only once (Not when a change occurs, it is what `ChildEventListener` does, waits a change to occur), you can use `ListenerForSingleValueEvent`:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            beacon addBeacon = dataSnapshot.getValue( beacon.class );
            LatLng coord = new LatLng(addBeacon.latitude, addBeacon.longitude);
            marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(coord)
                .title("Hello world"));     
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @merterpam I will try to follow it and let you know if i face some trouble.

Comment: I created the marker option as you explained but as for retrieving part i am not sure how to use "addBeacon" variable. Another thing is my idea is to scan beacon with certain UUID and upload it on firebase along with my GPS coordinate, everytime i detect the same UUID  i want to update it rather then making new value.Then i want to retrieve the latest value of that specific beacon. It's little confusing.

Comment: I thought you can use it to create a Marker, but I guess your logic is a little more complicated. If you add a with the same key (not push, but direct setValue), then Firebase behaves like a Map, it overwrites the old value. As for the delay you mentioned, I'm not exactly sure why it happens, the delay should not be too excessive.

Comment: Yes what you are saying works but with a small problem. i can scan more than 1 beacon but it updates only 1 and another 2 beacons aren't uploaded. with the following commands:


  addBeacon.latitude = mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                    addBeacon.longitude = mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
                    databaseReference.child( "foo" ).setValue( addBeacon);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: If UUID is unique for each beacon, maybe you can add it to the database like this ( and later on update using UUID): databaseReference.child( "foo" ).child(addBeacon.UUID).setValue( addBeacon);

Comment: Thanks a lot . Now it's working perfectly fine ! The only issue left is retrieving. But anyways thanks again.